# Telegram Bot API дублирует сообщения

Tags: php, telegram, бот

При отправке сообщения боту, он начинает дублировать его. (см.скрин) 
Сам бот привязан через webhook. Вот мой код:
PHP 8.0

```
<?php 
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$text = $data['message']['text'];

define('TOKEN', 'тут токен');

function sendTelegram($method, $response) {
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.telegram.org/bot' . TOKEN . '/' . $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $response);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $res;
}

if (!empty($text)) {
    if (mb_stripos($text, '/start') !== false) {
        sendTelegram(
            'sendMessage',
            array(
                'chat_id' => $chat_id,
                'text' => "success"
            )
        );
        
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где я ошибся? Спасибо!

Comment: Скорее всего ваш код просто вызывается два раза. Т.е. ошибка где-то в той части, где "привязан через webhook"

Comment: Т.е. надо смотреть в сторону NGINX + PHP-FPM?

Comment: Я думаю, что это просто разные евенты. Я бы начал с того, что залогировал бы содержимое $data при каждом запросе и посмотрел, во первых, действительно ли они приходят по два раза и во вторых - одинаковые ли оба запроса для одного и того же сообщения или там есть что-то, за что можно зацепится, чтоб отбросить лишние

Comment: Кстати, еще один вариант - вы повесили вебхук дважды. Тоже стоит проверить

Comment: @Darth нельзя повесит вэбхук дважды на одного бота.

Comment: какая-то забавная арифметическая прогрессия числа отправленных `success` сообщений. Это весь код?